# how to install custom rom on mmx bolt a35

Tags: recovery-mode, rom

I want install the dream xperia a35 custom on my mmx a35. 
I downloaded the base rom and main rom but how to install them in cwm recovery how to install the base rom and then main rom if base rom can be installed by install zip from sd card but how to install the main rom when where can i need to reboot mobile to install 2nd zip
give me both procedure with links detailed
thank you

Answer (score 0):

It is an easy process but you can use only custom roms on the device. Just have look at this link 
https://lifehacker.com/how-to-flash-a-rom-to-your-android-phone-30885281